# How to check that text is changed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am just start to learn WPF and have a questions:

My DataContext is some XElement with attribute str, in markup I added:

```
        <TextBox x:Name="NumStr" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,257,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path = Attribute[str].Value}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Now if text in NumStr is changed I want to create some code:

```
if (element.Attribute("str")?.Value != NumStr.Text && NumStr.Text != "")
                ContentFormControl.AddNumStr(fullPath, NumStr.Text);
```

But text in element.Attribute("str")?.Value change at the same time with NumStr.Text. How I can correctly check, that text is change. Create other variable I won't.

Thanks for answers, and sorry for my english.

Comment: If str attribute value will be not change, it solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Text property binding to OneWay:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Attribute[str].Value, Mode=OneWay}"
```

in this way the source property will not be updated every time you change the TextBox's text